# windows mobile application using GPS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

i want to build an app for windows mobile that can get GPS locations(longitude and latitude) and can save them in app as user wants and use them for comparing with the current location, for ex. the application have a capability for saving some locations as user wants(ex: her/his home and office position) every time the app can recognize the user's home and office, the application will not need internet and map for its work?

Comment: Do you want us to build it for you and send you the code? What exactly are you asking?

Comment: i meant which namespaces exactly used for having app like that, thanks for ColinE answered me,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can get geolocation data from the Windows Phone 7 GPS via the [GeoCoordinateWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinatewatcher.aspx)  class. And, no, the phone does not need internet access in order to obtain this information.